# Prove that V is a norm direct sum.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, direct-sum

(ex.4.16. from chapter 3 of "Advanced Calculus" by L.H.Loomis, S.Sternberg)

Let N be a closed subspace of a normed linear space, and suppose that N has a finite-dimensional complement in the purely algebraic sense. Prove that then V is the norm direct sum M(+)N.

The authors advise using the fact that if V and W are fin.-dim. normed linear spaces then every mapping in Hom(V, W) is bounded, and also using the projection P of V onto N along M.

The problem is that I don't understand what the "norm direct sum" is, and so I don't know what exactly I have to prove. There was no such definition in the theoretical material of the chapter. I could suggest what it means if there was, for example, "a norm on a direct sum", or something like that. But it's surely a different concept. And when I Google it the results are not what I'm looking for. Could you please explain what that concept means? Maybe it's just a mistake in the exercise?

Comment: The exercise appears on p.136 and the term “norm direct sum” is defined on p.134 (right below the proof of Lemma 4.1). A useful characterisation of norm direct sum is given in Theorem 4.5: an algebraic direct sum $V=\oplus_1^n V_i$ is a norm direct sum if and only if each associated projection $P_i:x\mapsto x_i$ from $V$ onto $V_i$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I overlook it